# Jest code coverage with wildcard path

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

Is it possible to create a coverage report with jest for files that satisfy a wildcard path? After the latest release of jest, I can finally create coverage for files specified in the "collectCoverageOnlyFrom" config object (I'm on a Windows platform). I would however like to specify wildcarded paths, instead of every single file. Am I doing it wrong, or is it not possible?

I've tried

```
"collectCoverageOnlyFrom": {
    "src/*.jsx": true,
    "src/**/*.jsx": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.js` format is possible.

```
"collectCoverageOnlyFrom": {
    "src/***.js": true
  },
```

Taken via [Unit test code coverage with jest](https://blog.sergiocruz.me/reactjs-unit-test-and-code-coverage-with-jest/)

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible for jsx?